# protected can't access in different package subclass why?

Tags: java

Error: `m1() has protected access in A`

When I try to using superclass reference variable (`A obj=new B()`)

This is a first class in package pkg1;

```
package pkg1;
public class A {
    protected void m1() {
        System.out.println("protected method");
    }
}
```

This is a second class which is in another package pkg2 importing pkg1;

```
package pkg2;

import pkg1.A;
public class B extends A {
    @Override
    protected void m1() {
        System.out.println("override m1");
    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        A obj=new B();
        obj.m1();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to access `obj.m1()` and `obj` is of type `A`. So...

Comment: Indeed. Please explain why you *expect* that to work. (And in future, please pay more attention to code formatting. I've fixed it up now, but it was a mess before.)

Comment: @denys Seguret , @ jon Skeet if i'm not worng java gives the mechanism of dynamic method dispatch ,so i think i can access the m1() method which is overriden from A by using of reference varible of type A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you're still slightly confused with why `protected m1()` isn't visible.

You understand that `main` is a method in `B` and `B` is a subclass of `A`, therefore you feel like it should be accessible.

The key is `obj` is cast to be interpreted of type `A`. Then you try to call **instance method** `m1` from **static** context in `B` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods) link above for why this is important). By class `A` definition, `m1` is accessible through:

1. Class definition itself on a given instance of itself.

```
//example 
package pkg1;

public class C {
    protected void m1() {
        System.out.println("protected method");
    }

   public static void callM1(C anInstanceOfC){
        anInstanceOfC.m1();
   }
}
```

```
package pkg2;

import pkg1.C;
public class D extends C {
    @Override
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("override m1");
    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        C obj=new D();
        C.callM1(obj);//output would be "override m1"
    }
}
```

2. Instance methods (of course) of the class within itself and of subclasses.

```
//example 
package pkg1;

public class C {
    protected void m1() {
        System.out.println("protected method");
    }

    public void m2() {
        m1();//call to instance method m1
    }

   public static void callM1(C anInstanceOfC){
        anInstanceOfC.m2();
   }
}
```

```
package pkg2;

import pkg1.C;
public class D extends C {
    @Override
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("override m1");
    }

    public void m3() {
        //super.m2()
        m2();//call to superclass method
    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        D obj=new D();
        D.m3(); // output "override m1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**protected** keyword means that you can access protected-defined data from child classes. In example, you try to access protected data from non-child static context. You should probably try this:

```
package pkg2;

import pkg1.A;
public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("override m1");
    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        B obj=new B();
        obj.m1();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ SeniorJD   when i extends A in class B that means B is the child of class A.

Comment: But `main` method is not a part of B object actually.

Comment: how main method is not a part of B object ?

Comment: You're confused with classes and objects concepts. `main` is a part of B class, but not a part of B object.

Comment: @SeniorJD I've never really thought about static methods like that, but you're right. [Difference between Static methods and Instance methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods)

Comment: sorry i'm new but i think i can access the child class member which are overriden from parent class by using parent type reference variable.

Comment: @Pushpam Kumar You can just not with the access modifier you are currently using for the `m1()` method. See other answers to your question to see how.

Comment: @PushpamKumar You did effectively override the `m1` function, just not the modifier in class `A`. If pass  you pass the `obj` back into a method in `A`, example. New method in `A`: `public void callM1(A a){m1();}`. Then in main: `obj.callM1(obj);`. The output: "override m1". You just do not have access to it from outside the `A` class context.

Comment: @SGM1 Sir What does this mean " just not the modifier in class A"
How can we override the modifier??

Comment: @PushpamKumar Modifiers mean "private", "protected", "public", and "default". You're not meant to change these properties as per the language construct. But, you can still manipulate them at a per instance level using reflection in Java.

Comment: @SGM1  but sir protected is allowed "different package subclass".

Comment: @PushpamKumar I was just stating, if you used [reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288393/java-reflection-private-method-with-parameters-best-approach) to force the call to `m1` you would still get "override m1".

Answer (score 0):

The access level of m1() is protected. Protected methods can only be accessed by subclasses **or by other classes in the same package**. From your **static** 'main' method, you can not call a protected **instance** method of a class in a different package. If class B was in the same package as class A, then you will have no error and your code would work fine.